# Loading data from Cassandra to Teradata

Tags: cassandra, teradata

How to load data from Cassandra to Teradata in real time? Or what are the possibilities that we can use (like some tools) to achieve this?

Comment: Did you check Teradata Listerner (http://www.teradata.com/products-and-services/listener) and/or Teradata Presto (http://www.teradata.com/products-and-services/Presto/Presto-Download)?

Answer (score 1):

CDC (change data capture) or Triggers could work depending a on how "realtime" and consistency requirements.

Triggers could end up sending data to teradata that timeout and fail to write. CDC can give you safe output from consistency standpoint but has a slower turn around time (~10 seconds) and is going to give duplicates per replica.